# change Wordpress Template CSS based on WP_Customize

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a Wordpress template and I want to have options in the built in Wordpress Customizer for things like accent color, custom font, etc. that will then be used throughout the template. However, this means that I can't just code static CSS and would have to pass a variable in somehow. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer at https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-create-a-custom-color-scheme-for-your-wordpress-theme-using-the-customizer/.

Here's the most relevant code:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-styles', get_stylesheet_uri() ); // This is where you enqueue your theme's main stylesheet
  $custom_css = theme_get_customizer_css();
  wp_add_inline_style( 'theme-styles', $custom_css );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

`theme_get_customizer_css()` here is a custom function that returns a string of CSS that directly overwrites any code in the main stylesheet pertaining to colors, for example. Because it is generated in PHP, `get_theme_mod()` can be used to check for/insert any customizer settings. Once this CSS is generated, `wp_add_inline_style()` adds it to the main stylesheet; if everything is coded properly, CSS's cascading nature will have the newly added code override the earlier code without any need for `!important` or anything like that.

I'm left wondering if, instead of overriding, the inline inserts can (or should) be the only declaration of CSS that could be possibly changed by the customizer, i.e. in `theme_get_customizer_css()` if there are no customizer options set return the default code rather than the default code being in the spreadsheet to start with. This would prevent there being tons of duplicate CSS, relying on cascade hierarchies to work, but the stylesheet would also be incomplete on its own, so maybe there's reason not to do this? Would love input if anyone has thoughts.